# Cannot get block-wise visual selections in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, vim-windows, visual-mode, visual-block

I am searching for how to get visual selection in vimscript. And I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61486601/4438921, it is great, but the only issue is that, in block-wise visual mode, I always get the previous visual selection, not the current one.

Is there a way to do it correctly?

Code from the link:

```
xnoremap <leader>a :<C-U> call GetVisualSelection(visualmode())<Cr>

function! GetVisualSelection(mode)
    " call with visualmode() as the argument
    let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
    let [line_end, column_end]     = getpos("'>")[1:2]
    let lines = getline(line_start, line_end)
    if a:mode ==# 'v'
        " Must trim the end before the start, the beginning will shift left.
        let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: column_end - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
        let lines[0] = lines[0][column_start - 1:]
    elseif  a:mode ==# 'V'
        " Line mode no need to trim start or end
    elseif  a:mode == "\<c-v>"
        " Block mode, trim every line
        let new_lines = []
        let i = 0
        for line in lines
            let lines[i] = line[column_start - 1: column_end - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
            let i = i + 1
        endfor
    else
        return ''
    endif
    for line in lines
        echom line
    endfor
    return join(lines, "\n")
endfunction
```

Comment: The solution seems to work fine for me. Could you elaborate slightly more about the problem you have. A concrete example would help I suppose.

Comment: Please [edit] to add detail from the linked answer such as code or other context. As written, your question is hard to understand on it’s own.

Comment: It would be good if you could adapt the question with your usage that made the original solution failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it.

From https://github.com/neovim/neovim/discussions/24055#discussioncomment-6213580

> > In that case, it seems I will miss the `<C-U>`, thus I cannot get the correct block-wise visual selection?
>
> In this context, those keys only delete `'<`,`'>` because it gets
> automatically inserted in the command line when you press `:` on
> visual mode. If you check `:h c_ctrl-u` you will see that this is what
> `<c-u>` does in command mode.
>
> > mayby I can try adding a normal! before calling the function: vim.cmd('normal! call getVisualSelection(visualmode())').
> > because based on another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051271/4438921, it says
> > `'<` and `'>` don't get updated when the user is still in visual mode.
> > That is the reason, that I cannot get the correct visual selection in getVisualSelection function.
> > But if now I try to add normal!, maybe it will first exit visual mode, then I can get the correct (e.g. the previous visual mode)
> > visual selection
>
> Yes, those marks are not set until you leave visual mode. But,
> `\<c-u>` has nothing to do with it, the thing that makes you leave
> visual mode in the vimscript mapping is `:` (because you enter command
> mode). So, if you wan't to force neovim to leave visual mode so the
> marks are set, you can use `vim.cmd.normal('')` (where  is what
> neoivm sees when you press `<esc>`). The full function would be:
>
> ```
> vim.keymap.set({ "x" }, "<leader>f", function()
>     vim.cmd.normal ""
>     vim.fn.GetVisualSelection(vim.fn.visualmode())
> end)
> ```

Comment: It would be good if, instead of a mere link, you could give the solution you selected.

Comment: You are not mentioning what the solution is.

Comment: Now I am confused. May be I did not understand the problem but copy-pasting this discussion here verbatim does not help with what problem you are trying to solve :/

Answer (score 0):

See [`:h col()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#col%28%29)

```
The result is a Number, which is the byte index of the column
position given with {expr}.  The accepted positions are:
    .   the cursor position
    $   the end of the cursor line (the result is the
        number of bytes in the cursor line plus one)
    'x  position of mark x (if the mark is not set, 0 is
        returned)
    v   In Visual mode: the start of the Visual area (the
        cursor is the end).  When not in Visual mode
        returns the cursor position.  Differs from '< in
        that it's updated right away.
```

In short you need to check `col('v')`  and `col('.')` to get the cursor position and start of visual selection.